# How can i make the window.print() function look "prettier" in my html page?

Tags: javascript, html, pandas, printing

I was trying to print a table i created using pandas in my html page, so i used the window.print() function, the problem is that it doesn't have neither the bottom line nor the middle line between all the rows of the table.

The code i'm using to generate the table in my python script is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Nome': lnome, 'CEP': lcep, 'CPF / CNPJ': lcpfcnpj, 'Status':lstatus, 'Estado':lestado, 'Cidade':lcidade})
    #alf / lcl / cep
    if ordem == "alf":
        df = df.sort_values(by=['Nome', 'Estado', 'Cidade', 'Status'])
    elif ordem == "lcl":
        df = df.sort_values(by=['Estado', 'Cidade', 'Nome', 'Status'])
    
    global finaltable
    finaltable = df.to_html(classes='table', index=False)
```

And the code i'm using in html to print is:

```
    function imprimir() {
            // Hide the top bar
            document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.display = 'none';

            window.print()
            document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.display = 'flex';
        }
```

But when i try to print it turns from this: [How it looks like on my html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JbB0.png)

To this: [How it looks like after i use window.print()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYnXs.png)

I tried looking for diferent ways to print my html page but none of them were less "bugged"

Note that i DON'T want to adjust the font, the font color or anything, just the "bars" or "lines" that were supposed to be between the rows and at the bottom of the table (my main problem is the bottom)

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS you can use a print media query with table specific CSS.

```
@media print {
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  table tr td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```